# What types of data are supported in Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

What data types are supported in Memgraph? Is there a difference between node and relationship types? Do I need to define data type in similar way that you define variable types in programing languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph stores all of the data in nodes and relationships. There are some important differences when it comes to them:

- **Nodes** can have labels that are used to label or group nodes. A label is of the type `String`, and each node can have **none or multiple labels**. Labels **can be changed at any time**.
- **Relationships** have a type, also represented in the form of a `String`. Unlike nodes, relationships must have **exactly one relationship type** and once it is set upon creation, **it can never be modified again**.

Nodes and relationships can store various properties. Property names are represented as text, while values can be of different types.

Each property can store a single value, and it is not possible to have multiple properties with the same name on a single graph element. But, the same property names can be found across multiple graph elements.

There are no restrictions on the number of properties that can be stored in a single graph element. The only restriction is that the values must be of the supported types.

This are supported data types in Memgraph:

- `Null` - Property has no value, which is the same as if the property doesn't exist.
- `String` - Character string (text).
- `Boolean` - Boolean value, either true or false.
- `Integer` - Integer number.
- `Float` - Floating-point number (real number).
- `List` - List containing any number of property values of any supported type under a single property name.
- `Map` - Mapping of string keys to values of any supported type.
- `Duration` - Period of time.
- `Date` - Date with year, month, and day.
- `LocalTime` - Time without the time zone.
- `LocalDateTime` - Date and time without the time zone.